# Framework or tools to generate theorem prover/solver/reasoner for new logic

Tags: logic, sat-solvers, automated-theorem-proving, reasoning, smt-solvers

I have new logic which has syntax and semantics in usual natural languages and I have to create theorem prover/solver/reasoner for this logic. Is there framework or tool set that can generate such prover from the formal definition of grammar and semantics? I have heard about Isabelle/HOL, is this right set of tools. Is such generation a common path to proceed. Are the metalogical framework, prover compilers suitable for any kind of new logic?

Of course, I can create parser and encode all the algorithms by myself from scratch but this is not the common practice, I guess?

Comment: questions regarding programming tools are off-topic here.

Comment: @sasha I don't think the essence of the question is about tools, but about logics.

Comment: @MartinBerger my bad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many related ways  you can mechanise your logic.

- **Deep embedding** into one of the well-developed provers such as Isabelle/HOL, Coq or Agda. This is (almost) always possible, but makes using the embedded logic awkward.
- **Shallow embedding** into one of the well-developed provers such as Isabelle/HOL, Coq or Agda. This is only possible when the embedded and embedding logics are sufficiently similar, but when it works it tends to work well.
- **Embedding into Isabelle**. Note that Isabelle is a meta-tool for embedding logics, and Isabelle/HOL is but an implementation of HOL using the Isabelle tool. This is probably a lot of work, and moreover, most of the proof automation available for Isabelle/HOL is targetxing the logic HOL, so is unlikely to work for your specific logics.
- **Roll your own**. It's quite easy to build a proof checker, should be just a few lines of code, especially if you take the [LCF approach](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~jrh13/slides/manchester-12sep01/slides.pdf). More advanced tools are rather difficult, a modern SAT solver is probably > 10k LOC and that's for propositional logic, which is the simplest logic.
- **Logical frameworks**. Some $\lambda$-calculi have been built particularly to enable the embedding of logics. Most well-known might be the [Edinburgh Logical Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_framework) and [Pure Type Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_type_system). Some mechanismation of those is available, but whether that is usable for you I don't know.

Comment: Another approach would be using a logic programming language such as Prolog. In particular if you have a suitable proof system, proof search can be very quickly implemented.

Comment: I would recommend as a first try a tool for logical frameworks. You can use [Twelf](http://twelf.org/wiki/Main_Page) or [Abella](http://abella-prover.org), I'd recommend Abella. We recently switchted to it from Twelf for working with logics for programming languages, and we're happier now.

Comment: @godfatherofpolka I agree, logic programming is another option that I had forgotten about.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I have no personal experience with Abella, happy to believe it's more usable than Twelf. What kind of automation does Abella offer?

Comment: It's interactive, which helps a lot. And it performs "auto-like" proof search, while in Twelf you have to do everything with your bare hands.